# using elasticsearchoperations vs elasticsearchtemplate whats the difference?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rest-client

I am trying to figure out why I have to set my bean name to `elasticsearchTemplate`. Without it, my application crashes. I have the code below to configure my Rest client. The issue is if I don't add the `elasticsearchTemplate` as the bean name, it fails and says it cannot find `elasticsearchTemplate`. Any idea on why it does this and also what is the difference of using `elasticsearchoperations` vs `elasticsearchtemplate`?

```
Using Spring-Data-Elasticsearch Version 3.2
Using Java High-Level Rest Client Version 6.8.0
```

Works

```
@Bean("elasticsearchtemplate")
public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
}
```

Doesn't Work

```
public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because the startup configuration (application.properties) is missing the configuration related to elasticsearch.
You need to define some elastic search properties in your `application.properties` file such as **cluster-nodes**, **cluster-names** which are used by ElasticsearchTemplate and ElasticsearchRepository to connect to the Elasticsearch engine.
 as [follows](https://dzone.com/articles/elasticsearch-with-spring-boot-application)

Comment: But this doesn't answer the difference between them and why it's looking for `elastiscsearchTemplate` as a bean name?

Comment: I was able to find the answer. I will mark yours since it led me down the path. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can manually configure rest client by extending AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration.

```
@Configuration
public class RestClientConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {
  @Override
  public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {       
    return RestClients.create(ClientConfiguration.localhost()).rest();
  }
}
```

2. what is the difference of using elasticsearchoperations vs elasticsearchtemplate?

> The ElasticsearchTemplate is an implementation of the ElasticsearchOperations interface using the Transport Client.
> https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#elasticsearch.operations.resttemplate